# How do I get the current User Id with GoViral ANE

Tags: facebook, ane

I am using the GoViral ANE for integrating with Facebook, specifically creating a leaderboard to display in my game.

I would like to highlight the current user's score, but I don't appear to have access to the id that is returned via the APP_ID/scores request.

For example, data is returned in the following format:

```
{"score":123,"user":{"name":"Colin","id":"1234"}}
```

The id portion is what I am looking to match to the current user to highlight the score.

I have tried GoViral.goViral.getFbAccessToken() but this is clearly the wrong thing.
I have also tried making a call out to get the current user's score, but it also requires a User Id to make the call, so I am a little stumped on this one.

Searching on Google doesn't seem to return any useful results either.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it seems I don't need a user id to make the call after all.

The call I was attempting was the following:

From the [Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements) site:

> You can read the score for a person playing your game by issuing a
>   HTTP GET request to /USER_ID/scores with a user access_token.

With this code:

```
GoViral.goViral.facebookGraphRequest(
  GoViral.goViral.getFbAccessToken() + "/scores",
  GVHttpMethod.GET);
```

However the following call works:

```
GoViral.goViral.facebookGraphRequest(
  "me/scores",
  GVHttpMethod.GET);
```

So using "me" works instead of the user id, which returns:

```
{"score":123,"user":{"name":"Colin","id":"1234"}}
```

Allowing me to access the user id.